# There isn't a sofware package called "dbmail" in your current software sources

Tags: 11.10, apt, package-management, 8.04

where is [dbmail](http://dbmail.org/index.php?page=download)?

> [Binary packages]
>
> Most major distros already have packages for dbmail. Ubuntu, Debian,
>   Fedora en Gentoo are known to do so. So check your package manager.

From the console:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ aptitude search dbmail
thufir@dur:~$
```

Is there a better way to find dbmail?

Hmm, I do see that [it's available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/dbmail) for Hardy, but not for oneiric which I see.  Has it been replaced?  Is there an alternate?

Ok, clicked on the link and see:

[image]

However, I don't think that I can install it, I'm getting a message:

```
Not found.  
There isn't a sofware package called "dbmail" in your current software sources.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like dbmail was [Removed](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/oneiric/universe/base/dbmail) from this repository.  So you can download it from [Here](http://www.dbmail.org/index.php?page=download).  Download the latest, and install it.  For help in installing it [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file) will help.

Comment: I don't think that link works precisely because dbmail isn't in my current software sources.  I need to add a repository, perhaps?  Note that it's on http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/dbmail but **not** for 11.10.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be sure.  I try to use apt where possible.