# where or how to compile or download libzdb-devel

Tags: package-management, compiling, packaging, make

I'm trying to compile the development library for [libzdb](http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/), because dbmail requires this dev package to [compile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175607/there-isnt-a-sofware-package-called-dbmail-in-your-current-software-sources).

While I've downloaded and compiled the package from libzdb, this is just the regular binary, whereas what I need is the [devel](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libzdb-devel) package.

How can I build/get/download libzdb-devel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `libzdb-dev` which works on Ubuntu, please add this repository by adding this line to the end of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://debian.nfgd.net/debian unstable main
```

This only has zdb packages, so it shouldn't mess up anything else.

Then, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libzdb-dev`.

([Source](https://github.com/pjstevns/kwetter.core))

Comment: could I just install dbmail from that repo?  that's the end goal.

Comment: I don't know---I'm browsing from my phone right now so dont have access to the usual tools. I will look into this In a couple of hours and update.

Comment: no problem.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/175724/how-safe-is-deb-http-debian-nfgd-net-debian-unstable-main